# user can't send text to drop down with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to check drop down.
I have a scenario:
A user only can choose from drop down but doesn't send a text.
How to check that user can't send the text?

Comment: You have to be more elaborative. No body will help you if you can not just provide the whole information like relevant HTML , error stack trace , code that you've written etc.

Comment: When its just a dropdown and there is no way a user can type then why do you need to check send text? Or the drop down contains text field too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Select select = new Select(webElement);
//Select by index
select.selectByIndex(index);
//Select by value
select.selectByValue(value);
```